# ¿existe alguna Libreria para reconocimiento de Voz en Java?

Tags: java, java-swing, javafx, java-8

ya he buscado sobre mi pregunta que formule, y queria saber si ustedes saben de alguna libreria y como utilizarla?.

si pudieran pasarme un tutorial, pdf, etc se lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Hola @Jorge. Esta pregunta busca respuestas basadas en opiniones, algo que se intenta evitar y que puede terminar cerrando tu pregunta. Quizás sea un tema más propicio para consultar en el [chat]

Answer (score 2):

pero por lo que he visto las mejores usan servicios en linea y son de pago, por ejemplo la de google.
Yo me decante por  [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) que es gratuita, pero me resultó un poco complejo empezar a utilizarla. En ese sentido te voy a hacer un copy past de un par de ficheros esenciales de mi proyecto para que te sirva como "tutorial" para empezar. Ya que yo no encontré un tutorial válido actualizado y me toco ir peleandome paso a paso.

Primero de todo, cree el proyecto como un proyecto de java maven. Y añadí ahí las dependencias de Sphinx.
EN el archivo pom.xml de la configuración de maven, añade(dentro de project, por ejemplo debajo de la etiqueta properties):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.cmu.sphinx</groupId>
        <artifactId>sphinx4-core</artifactId>
        <version>5prealpha-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.cmu.sphinx</groupId>
        <artifactId>sphinx4-data</artifactId>
        <version>5prealpha-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

He necesitado crear esta clase para transformar el wav a un fichero valido para que reconozca la librería ( el método empleado para el reconocimiento de voz es, grabar un audio, y a continuación, leerlo con la libreria. No es "on demand").

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

/**
 *
 * @author idelcano
 */
public class WavTool {

    static long RECORD_TIME = 10000;  // 10 seconds

    // path of the wav file
    File wavFile = new File("test.wav");

    // format of audio file
    AudioFileFormat.Type fileType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

    // the line from which audio data is captured
    TargetDataLine line;

    /**
     * Defines an audio format
     */
    AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
        float sampleRate = 16000;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
        int channels = 1;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits,
                channels, signed, bigEndian);
        return format;
    }

    /**
     * Captures the sound and record into a WAV file
     */
    void start() {
        try {
            AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();

            DataLine.Info info;
            info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();   // start capturing

            System.out.println("Start capturing...");

            AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);

            System.out.println("Start recording...");

            // start recording
            AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, wavFile);

        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes the target data line to finish capturing and recording
     */
    void finish() {
        line.stop();
        line.close();
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

    /**
     * Entry to run the program
     */
    public static void record(int time) {
        RECORD_TIME=time*100;
        final WavTool recorder = new WavTool();

        // creates a new thread that waits for a specified
        // of time before stopping
        Thread stopper = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(RECORD_TIME);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                recorder.finish();
            }
        });

        stopper.start();

        // start recording
        recorder.start();
    }

}
```

Y para probarlo cree este método (el ejemplo oficial no me funcionaba porque estaba obsoleto al menos en el momento en que lo probé, tienes comentados los archivos necesarios para un correcto reconocimiento de voz en ingles, pero sin comentar estan los que me descargue de la web que sale en comentarios y coloqué en la carpeta es en la raíz del proyecto.):

```
public void tryProgram() {
    WavTool.record(30);
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        //ENG
        //configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
        //configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
        //configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");
        //SPANISH downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Spanish/
        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("es/cmusphinx-es-5.2/model_parameters/voxforge_es_sphinx.cd_ptm_4000");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("es/es.dict");
        configuration.setLanguageModelPath("es/es-20k.lm");

        StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(
                configuration);
        File file = new File("test.wav");
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        recognizer.startRecognition(stream);
        SpeechResult result; 
        while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
            //recognized text
            System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n", Utils.fixEncode(result.getHypothesis())); 
        }
        recognizer.stopRecognition();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Y el método para corregir la codificación del texto reconocido por la librería al castellano:

```
public static String fixEncode(String hypothesis) {
    try {
        byte ptext[] = hypothesis.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
        String value2 = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
        return value2;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return "";
}
```